# Metadata MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME cannot be changed permanent

Tags: android

I use the code below to change the metadata field Title of all the videos.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "asd2");
    if (context.getContentResolver()
            .update(uri, values, null, null) == 1) {

        Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "Updated ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
```

The metadata is changed when i view the file in the sd_card. But when i copy the file somewhere else in my pc the title field from the details of the video file is blank.

Comment: i sure this will not change internal meta-data of video

Comment: do you know a way to change it?

Comment: only one solution to do this FFMPEG